# Как пишется первое слово?

Tags: грамматика

Дефис, раздельно?

> компетентностно ориентированных ситуативных тренингов

Answer (score 2):

Раздельное написание здесь возможно лишь если считать это слово словосочетанием, чему препятствуют, во-первых, его терминологический характер, во-вторых, семантическая неполнота слова *ориентированный*. Согласно § 80 п. 2 «Правил русской орфографии и пунктуации» 1956 г. (действующих по сей день), подобные прилагательные следует писать слитно. Однако в данном конкретном случае я бы рекомендовал дефисное написание, и вот почему. Существует орфографическая тенденция замены слитного написания дефисным при наличии в первой части сложного прилагательного суффикса относительных прилагательных или причастий (в нашем случае *-н-*), который выражает формально её грамматическую независимость. Именно на эту тенденцию ориентируются, в частности, авторы уважаемого словаря-справочника «Слитно или раздельно?» Б.З. Букчина и Л.П. Калакуцкая. На неё же опираются и авторы полного академического справочника «Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации» 2006 г.